# Unable to get previously checked values of form in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

While updating the form, my meetupform.controls.day array is not holding the previous values checked

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="meetupForm.controls.recurring.value==='weekly'">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="onDayChange(day, $event.checked)" *ngFor="let day of days" class="margin-lr" [checked]="isClassDay(day)">{{day}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
onDayChange(day: string, isChecked: boolean) {
const dayFormArray = <FormArray>this.meetupForm.controls.day;
if (isChecked) {
  // add to day array if checked
  dayFormArray.push(new FormControl(day));
} else {
  // remove from day array if unchecked
  const index = dayFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === day);
  dayFormArray.removeAt(index);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of your array every time your checked value is changed:

```
onDayChange(day: string, isChecked: boolean) {
   const dayFormArray = <FormArray>this.meetupForm.controls.day;
   ...
}
```

You need to make `dayFormArray` a property of the component to persist the value.

```
private dayFormArray: FormArray;

ngOninit(){
   this.dayFormArray = = <FormArray>this.meetupForm.controls.day;
}

onDayChange(day: string, isChecked: boolean) {
   if (isChecked) {
     // add to day array if checked
     this.dayFormArray.push(new FormControl(day));
   } else {
     // remove from day array if unchecked
     const index = this.dayFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === day);
     this.dayFormArray.removeAt(index);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already, but its the same. I am not creating a new array, just assigning the values of the meetusForm.controls.day into a new array which has nothing in it